# QCompleter doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, qcompleter

It's not showing any popup or error. It silently doing nothing.

```
QStringList dictionary;
dictionary << "exampleOne" << "Two" << "blah" << "hello";
dictionary.sort();
QCompleter * completer = new QCompleter(dictionary,ui->inRawText);
completer->setModel(new QStringListModel(dictionary, completer));
completer->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::PopupCompletion);
completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
completer->setWidget(ui->inRawText);
```

inRawText is instance of QTextEdit class.

EDIT: Signals (activated and highlighted) are not emited.

EDIT: Popup is shown only if I call complete() slot. It's stupid, I must reimplement QTextEdit class and it's keyPressEvent handler ... damned QT...

Comment: Here is an [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-customcompleter.html), it looks like it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: You probably have to connect QCompleter's activated signal to some slot.

Comment: yeah, but first it must show popup. It showing nothing... This signal is for obtaining choosen option.

Comment: When you solve a problem yourself, the right way to tell others about it at SO is to write your own answer. Then come back next day to accept it, to mark issue properly solved.

Answer (score 0):

Making a `QTextEdit` the parent of a `QCompleter` only affects the ownership hierarchy, it does not mean that the `QCompleter` must start processing text for the `QTextEdit`.

In fact, `QCompleter` does not function as an autocompleter for `QTextEdit`, it only works for `QLineEdit` and `QComboBox` and you use the `setCompleter()` function of those two classes to start the autocompletion.

Read the [documentation of `QCompleter`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qcompleter.html) for more information.

Comment: QCompleter work's with QTextEdit. -> http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-customcompleter.html.

Comment: It doesn't work automatically, you need to do a lot of the work yourself.